# Changing script from request to axios - log pending promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, request, axios, httprequest

I'd like some help please as I'm quite new in node.js and working with node packages.

I'm having the following script which makes a GET http request running on node using `request` which is *deprecated* now

```
const foo = (bar, callback) => {
  const url = 'https://some.api.com?key=abc123';

  request({url: url, json: true}, (error, response) => {
    if (error) {
      callback('Oops, there is an error!', undefined);
    } else if(response.body.foobarArray.length === 0) {
      callback('No data found', undefined);
    } else {
      callback(undefined, {
        foobar1: response.body.foobar1,
        foobar2: response.body.foobar2,
      })
    }
  });
}

console.log(foo('Hello')); // this logs {foobar1: 'Hello', foobar2: 'World'}
```

I'm trying to rewrite it using `axios` instead, so this is my code

```
const foo = async (bar) => {
    const url = 'https://some.api.com?key=abc123';

    try {
        const response = await axios.get(url);
        if (response.body.foobarArray.length === 0) {
            return 'No data found';
        } else {
          return {
            foobar1: response.body.foobar1,
            foobar2: response.body.foobar2,
          };
        }
    } catch (error) {
        return 'Ooops! Something went wrong :(';
    }
};

console.log(foo('Hello')); // This logs `Promise { <pending> }`
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here as I'm not very familiar how promises work exactly, but how can I fix this?

Comment: try `foo('Hello').then(result => {  }).catch(err=> {})`

Comment: @BrightFaith How do you return the data within `.then(result => { })` then? I tried `.then(response => { return { foobar1:response.body.foobar1, foobar2: response.body.foobar2}; })` but still getting the same issue `Promise { <pending> }`

Comment: you access the data inside `then` , how ever , you can still return something if you want 
`let myval = foo('Hello').then(result => { })` , you must be getting your `{ foobar1:response.body.foobar1, foobar2: response.body.foobar2};` inside `.then` as `result`

Comment: I'm sorry but I get confused, Can you give a more detailed answer of how the script should be? at the moment I'm returning the object with the data I wan't either inside the function or outside it when calling the function but still getting the same issue

Comment: checkout my answer and let me know the result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const foo = async (bar) => {
    const url = 'https://some.api.com?key=abc123';
    try {
        return await axios.get(url).then(response => {
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                if (response.body.foobarArray.length === 0) {
                    return reject('No data found');
                } else {
                    return resolve({
                        foobar1: response.body.foobar1,
                        foobar2: response.body.foobar2,
                    });
                }
            })
        }).catch(err => {
            return Promise.reject(err);
        });
    } catch (error) {
        // return 'Ooops! Something went wrong :(';
        return Promise.reject(`an error occurred : ${error}`);
    }
};
foo('hello').then(result => {
    console.log(result);
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(`error ! : ${err}`);
});
```

async functions returns a promise. async functions use an implicit Promise to return its result. Even if you don't return a promise explicitly async function makes sure that your code is passed through a promise
as you are using axios asynchronous , it's `response` is a `promise` which must be handled inside `.then().catch()` functions .
if no error occurs you can access the `response` inside your `.then()` , else you will have access to your `error` on `.catch()`
inside your `.then()` you can now do what you want with data , returning a new Promise , using `resolve()` for success and `reject()` for failure .

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 options here:

**Option 1**
Any async function returns a Promise (behind the scenes) so:

```
foo('Hello').then(console.log).error(console.error);
```

**Option 2**
You need to await for the result of foo function but, at the moment, you can't use await out of function scope level. So:

```
async function main() {
  try {
    const result = await foo('Hello');
    console.log(result);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
}

main();
```

In future Node.js releases, using await at global scope will be allowed.

Comment: How can you return the data you want then? still having the same issue `Promise { <pending> }`

Comment: Hi itdev. Which option did you try, option 1 or option 2? And, did you reproduce it with  async foo function?